# Prove that "sum of the degrees of two adjacent vertices is less than or equal to number of vertices"?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $d_G(v_i)$ be the degree of the vertex $v_i$ in $G$ which has $n$ vertices. Also $G$ is a triangle-free graph, so
we have $d_G(v_i) + d_G(v_j)\leq n$ for any edge $v_iv_j\in E(G)$.

how we can prove this: $d_G(v_i) + d_G(v_j)\leq n$ in general ??

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I want to prove that if we take two adjacent vertices of a triangular free graph then its degree sum is equal to or less than the number of vertices. I can check this to take different graphs but how I can generally prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This truth is contingent on the triangle-free nature of $G$. Because of this, the adjacent vertices represented in $d_G(v_i)$ and $d_G(v_j)$ are disjoint. If any vertex (say $v_k$) were common to both adjacent vertex sets, it would form a 3-cycle with $v_i$ and $v_j$, contradicting $G$'s triangle-free property given.

It's easy to see that this is not true for an arbitrary graph $G$; take for example the complete graph on $7$ vertices, $K_7$. Then the sum of degrees of any two adjacent vertices (all vertices are adjacent, of course) is $12$.